# SQL to bulk set wordpress image captions from spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I have a rather large spreadsheet that lists out all the images on a client site along with the image URL. It has updated information for the image `alt` attributes as well as new captions.

Since the list is so large, I'm looking for something like an SQL query or something I could run that would import the necessary information from the spreadsheet and update the related image metadata in the database. I'm not a backend guy, but the guy who usually handles this kind of thing is unavailable for a while, so it's fallen to me. Is this something I can do in MySQL?

edit: [I found this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229189/how-to-bulk-edit-canonical-urls-in-sql) that deals with what seems to be a similar issue. Would I be able to use this method for the image captions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone happens to want to solve a similar issue, here's how I solved it.
This post details where `alts` and `captions` live in the WordPress database: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/are-captions-stored-anywhere. I used that as the basis for my process.

First, I ran the following query on the `wp_postmeta` table and copy/pasted the results into a new sheet in my spreadsheet.

```
SELECT * FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE meta_key LIKE '_wp_atttached_file'
```

Second, I ran a similar query on the table `wp_posts` and also put the results in a new sheet.

```
SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE 'post_type' LIKE 'attachment'
```

I then used a Google Sheets (the spreadsheet software I'm using) add-on to merge each sheet with my main sheet. The `posts` data I merged on the basis of matching URLs (the data I have to work with in my original spreadsheet). Then I merged the `postmeta` data based on matching post IDs.

Finally, once I had all of that, I could download my file as a `.csv` file and import it into the `postmeta` and `posts` tables. I made sure to do my first import on a local install of the site so as to not screw with a live site. I'm using Sequel Pro for managing databases, and it has a handy CSV import tool that allows you to do an `UPDATE` on the `postmeta` and `posts` tables. My import used the post IDs and `meta_key` (for the alts) and `post_ID`/`ID` (for the captions) to match up the data.

That's the process that worked for me, though I still did have a dozen images with funky URLs that I just updated manually rather than messing around with Regex.